# ng2-pdf-viewer / pdf.js, render all pages in a PDF without container scrollbar but with working internal links

Tags: css, angular, hyperlink, pdf.js, ng2-pdf-viewer

**Desired result**: To render all pages in the PDF without the pdf-viewer container scrollbar and without breaking the internal links. The PDF in the demo has only two pages, actual PDF could have > 15.

I have tried several approaches, all culminating to set height of pdf-viewer container >= pdf heigh in order to get the pdf-viewer container scrollbar to disappear. Doing this breaks the internal links.

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwxumi?file=src/app/pdf-test/pdf-test.component.html

[style.height]="'50vh'" makes the internal links work, but pdf-viewer container now has a scrollbar.

[style.height]="'2500px'" makes the pdf-viewer container scrollbar disappear, but links do not work any more.

Maybe this is the wrong approach altogether? Please help me achieve the **desired result**